# Django URLs: Can't get the keyword arg into my view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

The URL pattern having issues is:

```
url(r'^$', business_list, name='business_list_home'),
url(r'^(?P<param>\w+)$', business_list, name='business_list_results'),
```

My view is:

```
@render_to('app/business_list.html')
def business_list(request, param=None):
    queryset = Business.objects.all()

    search_form = SearchForm
    print request.GET

    if param in request.GET:
        param = request.GET.get('param')
        if queryset.filter(city__iexact=param).exists():
            queryset = queryset.filter(city__iexact=param)
        elif queryset.filter(category__iexact=param).exists():
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__iexact=param)
        print queryset
    else:
        queryset = None
        print queryset

return {'business_list': queryset, 'search_form': search_form}
```

Essentially, I don't understand why when I go to /Miami I don't have access to it via `request.GET['param']` in the view? `print request.GET` prints `<QueryDict: {}>`

The reason I want to do this is to have a nice URL scheme for displaying results of businesses for the city or category (and that's why I check if it's a city or category in the view too) in the url. Let me know if there's a better way to accomplish this like

```
url(r'^$', business_list),
url(r'^(?P<city>\w+)$', business_list),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)$', business_list),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)$', business_list),
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should make your urls look like this `/city/Miami/`. What's happening now is that your first regexp `^$` captures all requests.

Comment: yup, I thought about that too. It's just that if I want to do something like <category>/<city>/<country>, using the obj prefix before would make it a pretty long url?

Comment: @limelights `^$` actually won't capture all requests. It'll only capture a URL with no path, e.g., "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`business_list` is a function that takes a request and a parameter called "param" (should probably give it a better name as to make it a little less generic). In Django, the URL routes can define what values get passed to the parameters of the view functions.

In the situation above, when a user goes to `/Miami`, Django will try to match the string `"Miami"` with any of the regular expressions defined in the URL routes. In this case, the matching expression is `^(?P<param>\w+)$`. When this match is made, the string `Miami` is captured into `param`.

Django will then call `business_list(request, param="Miami")`. Note that there were no query parameters passed in the URL (e.g., `/Miami?color=blue`).

The issue in the code you've written above is that you're checking to see not if `param` exists, but rather that `param` was passed in the query parameters. Try going to the URL `/Miami?param=test` and it'll probably work the way that you expected.

The real fix here is to not reference `request.GET`, because using GET parameters is exactly what you're trying to avoid. So, instead of

```
if param in request.GET:
    param = request.GET.get('param')
    if queryset.filter(city__iexact=param).exists():
        queryset = queryset.filter(city__iexact=param)
    elif queryset.filter(category__iexact=param).exists():
        queryset = queryset.filter(category__iexact=param)
    print queryset
```

Just do:

```
if param:
    if queryset.filter(city__iexact=param).exists():
        queryset = queryset.filter(city__iexact=param)
    elif queryset.filter(category__iexact=param).exists():
        queryset = queryset.filter(category__iexact=param)
```

Comment: You're definitely right about using a better word than `param`. I had started off with `city` and `category`, but came to the conclusion that it needed to be generic bc anything can get passed in, or no? Maybe something like `first_filter_param`?